# How to put div on progress tag

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have progress tag which imitate progress bar for video. In this case video last 100 seconds and we are currently at 80 seconds.

I would like to place a div square in 50 seconds of the video (on our progress bar):

So my expected result will be:

[image]

I have no idea how I can set such a div to just 50 seconds, because in future I would like to have more than one div to be place on this progress bar for many different second

```html
<progress value="80" max="100" />
```

Comment: It's better to reimplement `<progress>` instead

Comment: Do you need them to be divs? And do you want to place them at regular intervals?

Answer (score 0):

```css
progress {
  position: relative
}
progress::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  left: calc(var(--x) - 5px)
}
```

```html
<progress value="80" max="100" style="--x: 25%" />
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to work in Safari, I think progress elements support before and after pseudo elements in only some browsers (?Blink??).

Comment: Answers should never be just code dumps. Please explain your answer fully for the OP and the rest of the visitors to this question

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I am getting all the information about the size of the progress tag and its position relative to the viewport using `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`

Then set the position of the new div as per the dimensions.

```js
let progressBarDOMData = document.getElementById('foo').getBoundingClientRect();

let extraDivEle = document.getElementById('sample');

extraDivEle.style = 'padding-top:' + progressBarDOMData.height + 'px';

extraDivEle.style.left = progressBarDOMData.width / 2 + 'px';
extraDivEle.style.top = progressBarDOMData.y + 'px';
```

```css
.sample {
  background-color: #e41111;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<progress value="80" max="100" id="foo"></progress>
<div class="sample" id="sample"></div>
```